# action script2.0 help

Tags: actionscript

in flash  when i click on button this open a new window. but i need this in self window.

my action script is that

on (press) {
    getURL("index.html", _self);
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument for "window" should be enclosed in quotes:

```
on (press) { getURL("index.html", "_self"); }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using quotes around the second argument?

```
on (press) {
  getURL("index.html", "self");
}
```